# Shopify Metafield Variant Archive = True

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, conditional-operator

My main issue is,  I got lots of products here on shopify, and some of products has Variants as well.   My concern is some of variants aren't available on this season, so I assign them into metafields (see the image below).

Now I want all product Variants who assign in Metafield with a name type of "Variant Archive = true" are  going to hide in front-end page.

Newbie in Shopify hope anyone can help me with.

Newbie in shopify, Hope there's anyone can help me with.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlR7I.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9uLh.png)